# Does visual studio 2017 have support for bash and linux virtualenv for Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2017

Does visual studio have support for bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10? Is it possible to work inside linux `virtualenv`(Django) with visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of... you can use PTVSD in your django project :

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach('your_secret')
```

Then launch it. In VS go to "Debug"|"Attach to process..."
Choose "Python Remote (PTVSD)" as connection type and in the target :

```
tcp://yoursecret@localhost:5678/
```

make sure you have the 'display processes from all users" checked and click "Refresh".

Not really fast, but working.
More informations on this post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-cross-platform-remote